# PhpStorm Xdebug stuck on past breakpoint

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, xdebug

I did not find any solution or post about this so I might as well try it here.

I am using PhpStorm with Xdebug and Docker. The debug is working - that is not an issue.

What sometimes happens for unknown reason is - when I remove the breakpoint, the website still breaks on that specific point.

I did not find what exactly causes this as I can remove other breakpoints afterwards with no issues whatsoever, but this old breakpoint I remember I used in past is still stuck here.

I tried placing the breakpoint again and removing it - no effect.
I tried placing the breakpoint and setting the breakpoint not to break - no effect.

Restarting PhpStorm / PC / Docker / Xdebug reconfig did not help.

Is there anything else I could try?

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Open your Bookmarks toolbar/panel -- it has a section for Breakpoints. Make sure that there is no breakpoints left there. Try also cleaning all entries from the Watches panel.

Comment: P.S. It meant to be "toolwindow" instead of "toolbar"... My mistake (thinking about one word by typing another).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @LazyOne for suggestion.

When opening the bookmarks toolbar / panel, the breakpoint was still there, even though it was not visible in the editor itself.

Removing it from there solved the issue.

Thank you so much, did not know this menu existed till today.